# How can I check in xlib if window exists?

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I am writing c++ library in Linux using gcc.
Program opens web pages in new browser windows with

```
system("firefox https://www.webpage.com");
```

After that I use xlib to determine identifiers of each opened browser window. 
Then program raises firefox windows one by one using

```
XRaiseWindow(display, window)
```

in order to make a screenshot of each window and OCR.

But if I close browser window manually and try to use 
`XRaiseWindow` with the corresponding identifier it generates **BadWindow** error and terminates the program.

So how can I check in xlib if window with given `window` identifier exists?

Answer (score 5):

From the [X FAQ](http://www.phy.ohiou.edu/computer/xwin/xfaq.html):

> > **169) How do I check whether a window ID is valid?**
> >     My program has the ID of a window on a remote display.
> >     I want to check whether the window exists before doing anything with it.
>
> Because X is asynchronous, there isn't a guarantee that the window
>   would still exist between the time that you got the ID and the time you
>   sent an event to the window or otherwise manipulated it. What you should
>   do is send the event without checking, but install an error handler to
>   catch any `BadWindow` errors, which would indicate that the window no
>   longer exists. This scheme will work except on the [rare] occasion that
>   the original window has been destroyed and its ID reallocated to another
>   window.
>
> You can use this scheme to make a function which checks the validity
>   of a window; you can make this operation almost synchronous by calling
>   `XSync()` after the request, although there is still no guarantee that the
>   window will exist after the result (unless the sterver is grabbed). On the
>   　whole, catching the error rather than pre-checking is preferable.

Long story short: You can't :P  You can only damage control.